# Compile time errors - why do I have to keep re-compiling

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Back in the day, when I worked on WinForms projects in visual studio (2003 or 2005) when I compiled, if there were compilation errors, the IDE would catch the errors and display them in the error list window. I could correct all the errors, recompile, and everything would be fine. Since switching over to ASP .Net development, this is not the case. In visual studio 2010, I compile, I get some errors, I fix them, I recompile, and now new errors are listed that were not caught the first time. Can I force visual studio to catch all the errors the first time?

Comment: This is not, in general, how compilers work.  A simple typo in a declaration or a missing `}`, is capable of generating a *lot* of additional errors.  So a compiler makes an effort to suppress such useless extra errors.  This can however never be perfect because it has to make too many assumptions what the code *should* have looked like.  ASP.Net just has a lot more of such possible hazards.

Comment: Adding to @HansPassant 's comment, when later C++ compilers and IDEs stopped spitting out 60 different error messages over one little typo, people usually considered it to be a reduction in "noise" and clutter.